# boost::serialization: object with private default constructor works in a vector, but not in a map

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap, boost-serialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

class Foo{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(i);
    }
    int i;
    Foo():i(0){}
public:
    Foo(int k):i(k){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector< Foo> f;
    f.push_back(Foo(12));
    std::ofstream os("path");
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(os);
    oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", f);
    os.close();
    std::vector<Foo> g;
    std::ifstream is("path");
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(is);
    ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", g);
}
```

Which works fine when serializing a vector of Foos. However, if I try to serialize a map of Foos, it fails on the private default constructor:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> f;
f.insert(std::make_pair("hello", Foo(12)));
std::ofstream os("path");
boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(os);
oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", f);
os.close();
std::map<std::string, Foo> g;
std::ifstream is("path");
boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(is);
ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", g);
```

fails with

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/serialization/nvp.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/utility:70:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:109:18: error: field of type 'Foo' has private default constructor
      : first(), second() { }
                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:132:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo>::pair' requested here
        ::new(t)T;
                ^
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:93:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::serialization::access::construct<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> >' requested here
    access::construct(t);
            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:158:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::serialization::load_construct_data<boost::archive::xml_iarchive, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> >' requested here
        load_construct_data(ar, t, v);
        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/detail/stack_constructor.hpp:58:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl<boost::archive::xml_iarchive, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> >' requested here
        boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(
                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/collections_load_imp.hpp:83:48: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::serialization::detail::stack_construct<boost::archive::xml_iarchive, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> >::stack_construct' requested here
        detail::stack_construct<Archive, type> t(ar, v);
                                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/collections_load_imp.hpp:158:16: note: (skipping 12 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
        hint = ifunc(ar, s, item_version, hint);
               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:66:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::load<boost::archive::xml_iarchive, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Foo, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> > > >' requested here
        archive::load(* this->This(), t);
                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:86:39: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Foo, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> > > >' requested here
        this->detail_common_iarchive::load_override(t.value(), 0);
                                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:93:38: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Foo, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> > > >' requested here
        basic_xml_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(t, 0);
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:60:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::xml_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<const boost::serialization::nvp<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Foo, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> > > > >' requested here
        this->This()->load_override(t, 0);
                      ^
main.cpp:50:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::operator>><const boost::serialization::nvp<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Foo, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo> > > > >' requested here
    ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", g);
       ^
main.cpp:34:5: note: implicitly declared private here
    Foo():i(0){}
    ^
```

I'm using clang 
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)

and boost version 1.55 as shipped with Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I have tried providing the load_construct_data() function as follows:

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<class Archive>
        inline void load_construct_data(Archive &archive, Foo*a, unsigned int
file_version)
        {
            ::new(a)Foo(0);
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm still getting the same error, because it requires the constructor when instantiating a std::pair

Comment: This turned out to be a much more involved question than I anticipated. Well-done for asking.

Comment: The fix for this has been checked into the develop and master branch and will appear in the next release. If you can't wait for that, you can clone/download the latest versions from github.

Answer (score 5):

Oh. Aha.

I just used Boost 1.57.0 to compare the situation with `map<string, Foo>`.

Well, you're in luck. You've found another library version dependency (likely a bug).

- Not using that, but providing the private default constructor, GCC 4.8.2 compiles it just fine: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dffbdecfc590338)** **<sup>[1]</sup>**
- GCC 4.9.0 fails to compile it though (it uses a newer version of the standard library too). The `std::pair<>` default constructor fails to compile there, since `Foo` is not default constructible: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0412b0d053d76ba2)**

### Solution

Luckily the solution with  `save_construct_data`/`load_construct_data` saves the day, again.

However, you need to cater for the fact that the element type is *actually* not `Foo`, but `std::pair<T const, Foo>`.

```
template <class Archive, typename K> inline friend void save_construct_data(Archive& ar, std::pair<K, Foo> const* v, const unsigned int) {
    std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("first", v->first);
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("second", v->second.i);
}
template <class Archive, typename K> inline friend void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, std::pair<K, Foo>* v, const unsigned int) {
    std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    typename std::remove_cv<K>::type first;
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("first", first);
    int tmp;
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("second", tmp);
    new(v) std::pair<K, Foo>(first, tmp);
}
```

Now it all works:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d77bf6a838233eb0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &, const unsigned int) {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

    template <class Archive, typename K> inline friend void save_construct_data(Archive& ar, std::pair<K, Foo> const* v, const unsigned int) {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("first", v->first);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("second", v->second.i);
    }
    template <class Archive, typename K> inline friend void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, std::pair<K, Foo>* v, const unsigned int) {
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        typename std::remove_cv<K>::type first;
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("first", first);
        int tmp;
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("second", tmp);
        new(v) std::pair<K, Foo>(first, tmp);
    }

    int i;

  public:
    Foo(int k) : i(k) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo const& foo) {
        return os << "Foo { " << foo.i << " }";
    }
};

namespace boost { namespace serialization {


} }

int main() {
    using Data = std::map<std::string, Foo>;
    std::cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_VERSION << "\n";

    {
        auto f = Data { {"a", 12 }, {"b", 42} };
        //for (auto& e : f) std::cout << e.first << ", " << e.second << "\n";
        std::ofstream os("path");
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(os);
        oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", f);
    }

    {
        Data g;
        std::ifstream is("path");
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(is);
        ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("f", g);

        for (auto& e : g)
            std::cout << e.first << ", " << e.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Boost version: 105700
void save_construct_data(Archive&, const std::pair<K, Foo>*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive; K = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
void Foo::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive]
void save_construct_data(Archive&, const std::pair<K, Foo>*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive; K = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
void Foo::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive]
void load_construct_data(Archive&, std::pair<K, Foo>*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive; K = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
void Foo::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]
void load_construct_data(Archive&, std::pair<K, Foo>*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive; K = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
void Foo::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]
a, Foo { 12 }
b, Foo { 42 }
```

---

**<sup>[1]</sup>** (I can't link it on Coliru because the boost libraries there have been recompiled to the GCC 5.0 ABI)

### Notes

A better, general, solution would be to do the `load/save_construct_data` trick generically for non-default-constructible types in the `boost::serialization` namespace. That way, people won't have to "know" about the `std::pair<>` implementation detail. They could just implement `load/save_construct_data` for their own user-types and it would JustWork™ whether they put it in a vector or a map.

Implementing that generically is less-than-trivial though, and might interfere with some other machineries internal to the Boost Serialization framework.

I'll prefer to get some help of the Boost Serialization maintainers to do that in a reliable way. So, it seems I'll be submitting two tickets today.

Comment: A better, general, solution would be to do the `load/save_construct_data` trick generically for non-default-constructible types in the `boost::serialization` namespace. That way, people won't have to "know" about the `std::pair<>` implementation detail. They could just implement `load/save_construct_data` for their own user-types and it would JustWork™ whether they put it in a vector or a map.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this. Please post the trac ticket numbers as soon as they are in the system.

Comment: Posted this as a feature request here https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11343

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't necessarily work for vector either. Vector deserialization resizes the vector to the required size first. This requires the elements to be default-constructible.

Note how this is only a problem because

1. construction is not accessed via the `serialization::access` friend "token"
2. the class is default constructible

---

### The Documented Solution

The documentation [tells you to use `save_construct_data` and `load_construct_data`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors) for types that are not default-constructible.

Specifically they promise it will work for STL containers of these as well:

> In addition to the deserialization of pointers, these overrides are used in the deserialization of STL containers whose element type has no default constructor.

In practice, this works well in v1.57.0:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94649ad50c8b48f1)</kbd>**

But in 1.58.0 it isn't true...

### A Bug In Boost 1.58.0

Version 1.58.0 seems to have broken this:

The code seems to do required check (from `serialization/vector.hpp` in the unoptimized version of `load(...)`):

```
if(detail::is_default_constructible<U>()){
    t.resize(count);
    // ... snip ... 
}
else{
    t.reserve(count);
    // ... snip ... 
}
```

However, this does the check at runtime. The method will statically refuse to compile. Oops.

### The Fix

Instead of having the branches in the same flow code, it should be dispatched so that only the applicable branch is instantiated. I tested with this simplistic approach:

```
namespace sehe_bugfix {
    template<class Archive, class U, class Allocator>
    inline void load_elements(
        Archive & ar,
        std::vector<U, Allocator> &t,
        const unsigned int /* file_version */,
        collection_size_type count,
        mpl::true_
    ){
        const boost::archive::library_version_type library_version(
            ar.get_library_version()
        );
        item_version_type item_version(0);
        if(boost::archive::library_version_type(3) < library_version){
            ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(item_version);
        }
        t.resize(count);
        typename std::vector<U, Allocator>::iterator hint;
        hint = t.begin();
        while(count-- > 0){
            ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", *hint++);
        }
    }

    template<class Archive, class U, class Allocator>
    inline void load_elements(
        Archive & ar,
        std::vector<U, Allocator> &t,
        const unsigned int /* file_version */,
        collection_size_type count,
        mpl::false_
    ){
        const boost::archive::library_version_type library_version(
            ar.get_library_version()
        );
        item_version_type item_version(0);
        if(boost::archive::library_version_type(3) < library_version){
            ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(item_version);
        }
        t.reserve(count);
        while(count-- > 0){
            detail::stack_construct<Archive, U> u(ar, item_version);
            ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", u.reference());
            t.push_back(u.reference());
            ar.reset_object_address(& t.back() , & u.reference());
        }
    }
}

template<class Archive, class U, class Allocator>
inline void load(
    Archive & ar,
    std::vector<U, Allocator> &t,
    const unsigned int file_version,
    mpl::false_
){
    const boost::archive::library_version_type library_version(
        ar.get_library_version()
    );
    // retrieve number of elements
    item_version_type item_version(0);
    collection_size_type count;
    ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);

    sehe_bugfix::load_elements(ar, t, file_version, count, detail::is_default_constructible<U>());
}
```

And it works.

### SUMMARY

Sadly I don't have time now to investigate on the `map<>` situation. But I suspect that things are similar. The documented solution should still work. And it might still be broken.

I'll report the above issue later today to the issue tracker of boost.

I hope the answer helps you find the/a solution none-the-less

Comment: Issue reported here OT: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11342 _Boost Trac is debilitatingly slow :(_