# Register a type with no default constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize a derived class that does not have a default constructor. I am using the deserializing constructor pattern. I've read that you have to register the type of a derived class, so I am doing that in the output archive (`outputArchive.register_type<Point>();`). However, when trying to register the same type with the input archive, I get a compiler error that says `Point` does not have a default constructor (which it does not). What do we do in this case?

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
};

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:

    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    Point(TArchive& archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // Without this, we get unregistered void cast
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPoint>(*this);

        archive & mData;
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractPoint> point(new Point(7.4));

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive.register_type<Point>();
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    //inputArchive.register_type<Point>(); // Compiler error: no Point::Point()
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractPoint> pointRead(new Point(inputArchive));

    Point* castedPoint = dynamic_cast<Point*>(pointRead.get());
    std::cout << "Data: " << castedPoint->mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI I split this question between here and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753953/common-confusions-with-serializing-polymorphic-types

Answer (score 0):

In the case where a type doesn't have a default constructor, you can use `save_construct_data` and `load_construct_data`.

Note that these will **only** ever apply when serializing through pointers (for the obvious reasons).

Examples are here: [boost serialization of non-default constructible types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505615/boost-serialization-of-non-default-constructible-types/33510269#33510269) and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20save_construct_data)

Comment: I learned the other day (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722135/deserializing-construtor-doesnt-read-data-correctly) that I should use the deserializing constructor pattern. So you're saying this pattern only works when not serializing polymorphic type pointers?

Comment: @DavidDoria both your question code and the answer code seem a-typical Boost Serialization code to me. The question code is broken for reasons stated in the answer. I'm tempted to say the answer code is still wrong (it's hard to make it work reliably; I can't even begin to think how to combine it with Boost serialization of containers). So yeah, that answer didn't answer your real question because you were asking the wrong question then.

Comment: The point of not using `save/load_construct_data` was that if you don't have/want a pointer, then you shouldn't need to "fake" like you have/want a pointer in order to do the serialization.

Comment: @DavidDoria I guess the redux is, Boost Serialization really doesn't like non-default-constructibles. Like I said, I see how a "cheat" like that might work, but it will never jell with the framework