# Common confusions with serializing polymorphic types

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have seen many questions, tutorials, and documentation involving serializing derived classes, and I haven't been able to reach a consensus on several issues, including (and illustrated in the following code):

- `boost::serialization::base_object` vs `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP`
- `archive & mData;` vs `archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(mData);`
- The usefulness of `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(AbstractPoint);`
- Requiring `serialize()` for a class in the hierarchy that doesn't need to serialize anything.

Code:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;

    // Even though the class is abstract, we still need this
    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
};

// This doesn't seem to do anything
//BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(AbstractPoint);

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:
    Point() = default;
    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // These two seem equivalent. Without one of them, unregistered void cast
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPoint>(*this);
        //archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(AbstractPoint);

        // These two seem equivalent
        archive & mData;
        //archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(mData);
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractPoint> point(new Point(7.4));

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive.register_type<Point>();
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    std::shared_ptr<AbstractPoint> pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive.register_type<Point>();
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::shared_ptr<Point> castedPoint = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Point>(pointRead);
    std::cout << castedPoint->mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The other major issue is where to register classes in a "real" environment (when there is linking, etc.), but that seems worth a separate question.

It would be great to have a "gold standard" example of these kinds of things in the documentation, but at the least on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `boost::serialization::base_object` vs `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP`

The NVP wrapper is only ever required for archives that have element naming, like XML.

Unless you use it, `base_object<>` is cleaner and simpler.

- `archive & mData;` vs `archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(mData);`

Ditto

- The usefulness of `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(AbstractPoint);`

I assume it will merely be an optimization - suppressing registered type information with each archive type, since you told the framework it will never be de-serializing instances of the type

- Requiring `serialize()` for a class in the hierarchy that doesn't need to serialize anything.

You don't need it, unless you need the type information about a polymorphic base there. When do you need that? When you need to de-serialize pointers of the base type.

Hence, if you have

```
struct A{ virtual ~A(); };
struct B:A{};

struct C:B{};
struct D:B{};`
```

you *will* need serialization for `A` (but not `B`) if you (de)serialize `A*`. You will need serialization for `B` if you (de)serialize `B*`.

Similarly, if your type is not polymorphic (virtual) or you don't use it as such, you don't need any base serialization (e.g. if you (de)serialize `C` or `D` directly).

Finally, if you have `struct A{}; struct B:A{};` there is no need to tell Boost Serialization about the base type at all, (you could just do the serialization from within `B`).

### Update in response to your samples:

1. [case1.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d22dc9f69356feaf) looks ok
2. [case2.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a3958a630b507e6) **needs** to call base serialization, of course; not necessarily using base_object because you require polymorphic serialization:

   ```
   template<class TArchive> void serialize(TArchive& archive, unsigned) {
       archive & boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPoint>(*this)
               & mData;
       // OR:
       archive & static_cast<AbstractPoint&>(*this) 
               & mData;
       // OR even just:
       archive & mParentData 
               & mData;
   }
   ```
3. [case3.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45257bf4a4aeb9e8): indeed, it's exactly like case1, but with dynamic allocation and object tracking
4. [case4.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6ffb1329dc696cd): is exactly like case1, but with dynamic allocation and object tracking; **NB!!** it requires explicitly serializing for the base!

   ```
   template<class TArchive> void serialize(TArchive& archive, unsigned) {
       archive & boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPoint>(*this)
               & mData;
   }
   ```
5. [case5.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5eed5a5ba9d7e16): yes, but it's more typical to use the `CLASS_EXPORT*` macros from `boost/serialization/export.hpp`

> Bitrot insurance:
>
> - [case1.cpp](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15269929/)
> - [case2.cpp](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15269931/)
> - [case3.cpp](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15269932/)
> - [case4.cpp](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15269933/)
> - [case5.cpp](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15269939/)

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my answer (I intend to accept your answer, mine is just listing concrete examples of several cases) to see if everything looks ok and the concepts are demonstrated correctly? The last one is the most interesting - why do we not need to register the base class?

Comment: @DavidDoria Done, see updates with improved code for all cases:  [case1.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d22dc9f69356feaf),
 [case2.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a3958a630b507e6),
 [case3.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45257bf4a4aeb9e8),
 [case4.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6ffb1329dc696cd) and
 [case5.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5eed5a5ba9d7e16). Note the output for case2 and case4 where you can actually verify that the parent data was deserialized.

Comment: Thanks. Are these Coliru links permalinks (i.e. should I delete my answer and just keep the links in your updated answer? I still don't follow the use of `base_object` - in case2.cpp (and likewise case4.cpp), you are saying that we MUST call `boost::serialization::base_object` when I had actually showed that NONE of the OR's that you list are required and the base class serialize still seems to be called? (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b5f3eeca54e86a7)

Comment: @DavidDoria you failed to show that, by not checking wether parent data was serialized. See in my case2/4 where the values are 99 and 101

Comment: Oops, you're right. The value of `mParentData` that I thought had been deserialized was just from the initial value in the object that was read back in.

Comment: You got it :) `base_object` does indeed magically register some casts (and sometimes types) with the archive. Coliru is permalinks (though nobody knows what happens to websites in the future)

Comment: Would you like me to pull your code from Coliru directly into your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105196/discussion-between-sehe-and-david-doria).

Comment: I guess the confusion is not over :). Even without the type registration caused by pointers to parent classes, the deserializing constructor concept doesn't seem to work well when forwarding the archive up to a parents deserializing constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222439/deserializing-constructor-hierarchy/36223411?noredirect=1#comment60081089_36223411

Answer (score 1):

Following @sehe's advice, here are some example uses:

**Serialize derived class object, not forwarding to parent**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:
    Point() = default;
    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mData;
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    Point point(7.4);

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    Point pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::cout << pointRead.mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Serialize derived class object, including (automatic) forwarding to parent:**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;

    double mParentData = 3.1;

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mParentData;
    }
};

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:
    Point() = default;
    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // this is not required, the parent serialize() seems to be called automatically
        // archive & boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPoint>(*this);

        archive & mData;
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    Point point(7.4);

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    Point pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::cout << pointRead.mParentData << std::endl;
    std::cout << pointRead.mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Serialize derived class pointer, not forwarding to parent**
(note nothing changes from the object case)

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:
    Point() = default;
    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mData;
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Point> point(new Point(7.4));

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    std::shared_ptr<Point> pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::cout << pointRead->mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Serialize derived class pointer, forwarding to parent**
(note nothing changes from the object case)

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mParentData;
    }

    double mParentData = 3.1;
};

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:
    Point() = default;
    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mData;
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Point> point(new Point(7.4));

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    std::shared_ptr<Point> pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::cout << pointRead->mParentData << std::endl;
    std::cout << pointRead->mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Serialize base class pointer** 
(We now have to register the type of the derived class with the archives, as well as use `boost::serialization::base_object`)

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class AbstractPoint
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPoint(){}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;

    // This is required if we want to serialize an AbstractPoint pointer
    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
};

class Point : public AbstractPoint
{
public:
    Point() = default;
    Point(const double data) : mData(data) {}

    void DoSomething(){}

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // Without this, we get unregistered void cast
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPoint>(*this);

        archive & mData;
    }

    double mData;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractPoint> point(new Point(7.4));

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive.register_type<Point>();
    outputArchive << point;
    outputStream.close();

    std::shared_ptr<AbstractPoint> pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive.register_type<Point>();
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::shared_ptr<Point> castedPoint = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Point>(pointRead);
    std::cout << castedPoint->mData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```