# Is boost::serialization::base_object required every time I do inheritance?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I have:

- non-polymorphic (no virtual methods) class hierarchy;
- base class *already* contains `serialize`;
- child classes are serialized directly;

  ```
    class A
    {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;

        template<typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int)
        {
            ar & x & y;
        }
    };

    class B : public A { /* no data members*/ };

    class C : public A { /* no data members*/ };
  ```

1. Do I need `serialize` function in classes `B` and `C`?
   `serialize` function in `B` and `C` is exactly this:

   ```
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
    }
   ```
2. Should I expect some notes in documentation about this?

Comment: This is what the documentation says about this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#base . IMO this is misleading because this is only for a polymorphic (virtual methods) class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you don't want to serialize data from the base, you may not need it.

However, in polymorphic hierarchies you do need it if only to tell the archive about the registered types.

See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html

See here for lots of examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756430/85371

Comment: Thank you for answering and links, looks like it's more complex than I thought. Please let me clarify my question then to just confirm that I understood examples correctly.

Comment: I looked into samples you provided and they didn't seem to touch my case really. Thus the question was updated. Could you please have a look again?

Comment: So, no that doesn't require the base-class serialization. (This goes to show why a clear answer with code is always required. In my answer I assumed you had a base-class /without/ interesting members and the derived classes had everything, but yeah, the reverse also goes).

Comment: It would have been pretty easy to just try this out. In terms of _correctness_ my point about polymorphic types still stands: that's when you _do_ need it.

Comment: So should I expect the doc saying "you do not need this in your case"? Or absence of the opposite is enough?

Comment: It's a taste thing. I expect that a statement like "you do not need this" is going to lead to more problems than not. Also, the library doesn't really state you need it: it just tells you what to do to serialize (make sure it has a `serialize` member or a ditto free function accessible and visible via ADL)

Comment: Right, I was thinking exactly about this. e.g if I have free `serialize` accepting base class reference, it should just work, like in any other cases e.g. overriding `operator<<(ostream&`. Thank you!